# Insert Parents for all links in menu list

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to insert **h2** tags and make them parents for all links inside of a vertical navigation menu.

I can do this for a single element but now I want to do it for all elements within a menu.

JavaScript:

```
var menu_item = document.querySelector("div.righ-nav-style1 ul li a");    

// `menu_item` is the element you want to wrap
var parent = menu_item.parentNode;
var wrapper = document.createElement('h2');
wrapper.className = 'category_links';    

// set the wrapper as child (instead of the 'menu_item')
parent.replaceChild(wrapper, menu_item);
// set 'menu_item' as child of wrapper
wrapper.appendChild(menu_item);
```

I want to use the **replaceChild()** and **appendChild()** methods within a forloop for all menu items.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: add your solution in the answer section below

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:  I actually just found a solution to my problem.

Edited JavaScript:

```
// Replaced 'querySelector()' with 'querySelectorAll()' to get all elements
var menu_item = document.querySelectorAll("div.righ-nav-style1 ul li a");            

// Created 'for' loop to use 'replaceChild()' and 'appendChild()' methods for all elements
for (var i = 0; i < menu_item.length; i++){
  var parent = menu_item[i].parentNode;
  var wrapper = document.createElement('h2');
  wrapper.className = 'category_links';    

  // set the wrapper as child (instead of the 'menu_item')
  parent.replaceChild(wrapper, menu_item[i]);
  // set 'menu_item' as child of wrapper
  wrapper.appendChild(menu_item[i]);
}
```